# Use datatool to create circuitikz IC documentation from external file

Tags: circuitikz, datatool

I'm hoping to store data for N number of integrated circuits in simple CSV files and have the corresponding file drive the LaTeX document upon compile. See my MWE below and you see what I like to accomplish. The whole idea is to have "a single source of information" and not have to edit more than these CSV files in order to update the document.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=semicolon, string type}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{\currfilebase_pinout.csv}
1;Q1;Output 1
2;Q2;Output 2
3;Q3;Output 3
4;Q4;Output 4
5;Q5;Output 5
6;Q6;Output 6
7;Q7;Output 7
8;GND;Ground
9;Q7S;bla
10;/MR;bla
11;SHCP;bla
12;STCP;bla
13;/OE;bla
14;DS;bla
15;Q0;Output 8
16;VCC;2-6V
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) node[dipchip, num pins=16 ](C){\rotatebox{90}{\currfilebase}}; %num pins=... here I would be happy if datatool could give me the number of entries in the source file
    % ------------------- FROM HERE  ------------------- 
    \node [left, font=\tiny] at (C.pin 1) {Q1};
    \node [left, font=\tiny] at (C.pin 2) {Q2};
    \node [left, font=\tiny] at (C.pin 3) {Q3};
    \node [left, font=\tiny] at (C.pin 4) {Q4};
    \node [left, font=\tiny] at (C.pin 5) {Q5};
    \node [left, font=\tiny] at (C.pin 6) {Q6};
    \node [left, font=\tiny] at (C.pin 7) {Q7};
    \node [left, font=\tiny] at (C.pin 8) {GND};
    \node [right, font=\tiny] at (C.pin 9) {Q7S};
    \node [right, font=\tiny] at (C.pin 10) {/MR};
    \node [right, font=\tiny] at (C.pin 11) {SHCP};
    \node [right, font=\tiny] at (C.pin 12) {STCP};
    \node [right, font=\tiny] at (C.pin 13) {/OE};
    \node [right, font=\tiny] at (C.pin 14) {DS};
    \node [right, font=\tiny] at (C.pin 15) {Q0};
    \node [right, font=\tiny] at (C.pin 16) {VCC};
    % ------------------- TO HERE  -------------------  i would be happy if a macro could populate these data from the source file
    \end{circuitikz}
\caption{\currfilebase\ pinout}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \pgfplotstabletypeset{\currfilebase_pinout.csv}
    \caption{\currfilebase\ pinout explanation}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Example output:

[image]

Comment: Maybe https://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple?lang=en ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out using datatool:

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=semicolon, string type}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{;}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{\currfilebase_pinout.csv}
1;Q1;Output 1
2;Q2;Output 2
3;Q3;Output 3
4;Q4;Output 4
5;Q5;Output 5
6;Q6;Output 6
7;Q7;Output 7
8;GND;Ground
9;Q7S;bla
10;/MR;bla
11;SHCP;bla
12;STCP;bla
13;/OE;bla
14;DS;bla
15;Q0;Output 8
16;VCC;2-6V
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={Pin,Label,Info}]{csvData}{\currfilebase_pinout.csv}
\DTLmaxforcolumn{csvData}{Pin}{\numberOfPins}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) node[dipchip, num pins=\numberOfPins ](C){\rotatebox{90}{\currfilebase}};
        \DTLforeach{csvData}{\pinNumber=Pin, \label=Label}{
            \DTLdiv{\checkValue}{\pinNumber}{\numberOfPins}
            \ifthenelse{\DTLisgt{\checkValue}{0.5}}
                {\node [right, font=\tiny] at (C.pin \pinNumber) {\label};}
                {\node [left, font=\tiny] at (C.pin \pinNumber) {\label};}
        }
    \end{circuitikz}
\caption{\currfilebase\ pinout}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \pgfplotstabletypeset{\currfilebase_pinout.csv}
    \caption{\currfilebase\ pinout explanation}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! Maybe you can add the `circutitz` tag to the Q&A?

Comment: Done! I hope this can inspire someone else. :)